# How to pass the GET parameter to the composite component?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

I build a  composite component which takes an input id and generate a table . Then I make a page which accepts a GET parameter using `<f:viewParam>` likes this:

```
<f:metadata>
        <f:viewParam name="id" value="#{aBean.id}" />
</f:metadata>
<util:aCompositeComponent inputId="#{aBean.id}" />
```

The markup of the composite component is :

```
<cc:interface componentType="compositeComponentBacking">
    <cc:attribute name="inputId" type="java.lang.Integer"  />
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>         
        /**
          Use #{cc.result} to build a HTML table to present a result
        **/
</cc:implementation>
```

And the backing bean of the composite component is:

```
@FacesComponent("compositeComponentBacking")
public class CompositeComponentBacking extends UINamingContainer {

    private Integer inputId;

    public List<Result> getResult() {
        
        //Use inputId to query service to return result
        return result;
    }

    public Integer getInputId() {
        return inputId;
    }

    public void getInputId(Integer inputId) {
        this.inputId = inputId;
    }

}
```

GET parameter can be bounded to `#{aBean.id}` but `#{aBean.id}` cannot be passed into the composite component and it always remain null inside the composite component . How can I pass the GET parameter to the composite component?

---

**Update :**

I finally solve the problem .I found that when using the composite component  , if the input attribute is constant (eg `<util:aCompositeComponent inputId="1"/>`) ,this constant can be set to `CompositeComponentBacking` 's `inputId` field. But if I use the composite with the input attribute is an EL expression (eg `<util:aCompositeComponent inputId="#{aBean.id}"/>` , the value of the EL expression cannot be set to `CompositeComponentBacking` 's `inputId` field. I have to programmatically get the value by evaluating `#{cc.attrs.inputId}` inside `CompositeComponentBacking` . Is it the normal behavior ?

Comment: When you output `#{aBean.id}` on the page (outside of component), is the value set?

Comment: Yes . #{aBean.id} shown correctly if I put it beside the component , but inside the composite component  ,it is null.

Comment: Apparently you accessed/displayed it the wrong way inside the composite. Hard to tell if you don't show that part in the question.

Comment: @BalusC .please see my update. it seems that when using the composite component , if the input attribute is an EL expression, it cannot set to the component 's backing bean 's field. (i.e #{cc.inputId} is null) , I have to get the value by evaluating  #{cc.attrs.inputId}.

Comment: Isn't `#{cc.attrs.xxx}` the way to go for accessing parameters at the composite implementation? Still don't understand how are you trying to access to it... Are you trying to bind it to some property at your component type?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute values representing value expressions are set via [`setValueExpression("attributeName", valueExpression)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#setValueExpression%28java.lang.String,%20javax.el.ValueExpression%29), not via `setAttributeName(evaluatedValue)`. You know, JSF/Facelets EL is deferred, not implicit.

You should in the `getResult()` basically be obtaining the evaluated value by [`getAttributes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getAttributes%28%29) map:

```
public List<Result> getResult() {
    Integer inputId = (Integer) getAttributes().get("inputId");
    // ...
}
```

If you really want to add a getter and setter, then delegate to [`getStateHelper()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getStateHelper%28%29).

```
public Integer getInputId() {
    return (Integer) getStateHelper().eval("inputId");
}

public void setInputId(Integer inputId) {
    getStateHelper().put("inputId", inputId);
}
```

*(note: don't mix them; `getAttributes().get()` would scan for a getter first and then invoke it; if you were using `getAttributes().get()` inside the getter itself, it would call itself in an infinite loop causing an error represented by this site's name)*

Answer (score 0):

If you're certain the value is there, you can use

```
<util:aComposite inputId="#{param.id}" />
```

to access request parameter `id`. It won't be validated, converted or whatever.

Comment: already tried but still the same . The GET parameter cannot be pass to the composite component